# Does side-casting to and from sibling types preserve addresses in C++?

Tags: c++

If we compose calls to dynamic_cast and reach back to the original type on a pointer value, does C++ guarantee to preserve the value, assuming no dynamic_cast fails, i.e., does not return a nullptr?

I looked at the "Memory Layout in Virtual Inheritance" section in https://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/virtual_inheritance.html. This gave me a decent idea of how it can be implemented. From the looks of it, it seems impossible to get a different address. However, it is only one such implementation, I just want to be sure that no conforming implementation can return a different address than the original.

```cpp
#include <cassert>

struct A { virtual ~A() {} };
struct B : virtual public A {};
struct C : virtual public A {};
struct D : public B, public C {};

int main()
{
    B* b = new D();
    C* c = dynamic_cast<C*>(b);
    if (c != nullptr)
    {
        B* bp = dynamic_cast<B*>(c);
        assert(bp == b);  // Will this assert ever fire?
    }
    return 0;
}
```

A more general case:

```cpp
A* a = ...
dynamic_cast<A*>(dynamic_cast<B*>(...(a)...)) is `a` or nullptr
```

I ran the above code with gcc8 and clang9 and they don't fire the assert.

Comment: How did you build? In release builds assertions are ignored!

Comment: I changed == in assertion to != and it fired. I ran it on godbolt.org without specifying -O flag or defining NDEBUG.

Comment: What makes you think that the address might change? The object doesn't move around in memory neither do its bases.

Comment: In a multiple inheritance situation, pointers to bases will not necessarily be at the same address, but I can't think of a scenario where two pointers of the same type, aliasing the same data, would have different addresses, no matter how you obtained them. It would be pretty catastrophic if it were possible.

Comment: I am thinking along the lines of... Can any operation change the layout of the object during run-time? If so, then they may point to different addresses.

Comment: It seems impossible now since any such changes in the layout may invalidate any references to this object. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @MarekR - "release build assertions are ignored"  --  Not always. I have worked on several projects (all using make and g++) that shipped with assertions enabled, not ignored.   See also boost-for-windows which has a wonderful assert that adds debug features!  The <cassert> is very efficient when 'simple' condition is false, and useful as is.  It is trivial to make your own assert that does what you want upon condition true, either abort, or spin-wait, or whatever is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does side-casting to and from sibling types preserve addresses in C++?

Dynamic casting produces a pointer to the base / derived object, and that object has exactly one address. This applies to side casting as much as down casting.

Note that side cast may fail if the base is ambiguous due to having multiple non-virtual bases of the same type. Your example does not have such ambiguity. In such case, null will be returned.

> Can any operation change the layout of the object during run-time?

No. Layout of all objects is set in stone at their creation. In standard C++, the layout of all types is set in stone already on compilation, although there are language extensions such as *flexible array member* which can relax this.